# Use Same Recycler View Inside Multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler View in fragment 1, where I make network calls to download the images and pictures to populate each item.

Now, in the fragment 2, I want to show the same Recycler View (the one shown in the Fragment 1 after making network calls).

Can I do it without making network calls and downloading the images and text again in the Fragment 2?

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it you can store the details when you call it in fragment 1 in your sqlite database and then use it in fragment 2

Answer (score 0):

You may instantiate a common Recycler.Adapter and share the same instance with both the fragments